# Calling a FORM from select option

Tags: javascript, php, css

I have three forms, i want the first form to direct the user to either the second form or the third form and then send the $_POST of the selected form if the user fills it.

On my first form I have:

```
<form action="#" method="post">
<select name="load" onchange="changeOptions(this)>
<option> Please Select</option>
<option value="supervisor">Supervisor</option>
<option value="coordinator">Coordinator</option>
</select>
<input type="submit" value="load registration form">
</form>
```

for the java script i have:

```
<script>
function changeOptions(selectEl) {
  let selectedValue = selectEl.options[selectEl.selectedIndex].value;
  let subForms = document.getElementsByClassName('className')
  for (let i = 0; i < subForms.length; i += 1) {
    if (selectedValue === subForms[i].name) {
      subForms[i].setAttribute('style', 'display:inline-block')
    } else {
      subForms[i].setAttribute('style', 'display:none') 
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

I want if the Supervisor is selected and the SUBMIT Button is clicked, FORM2 Should be displayed and if Coordinator is selected and SUBMIT Clicked, FORM3 should be displayed.

on form 1 i have:

```
    <form class="className" id="coordinator" name="coordinator" style="display: none">
    ...... blah blah blah
<input type="submit" value="cordreg" value="Register">
    </form>
```

on form 2  have:

```
   <form class="className" id="coordinator" name="coordinator" style="display: none">
            ...... blah blah blah

<input type="submit" value="cordreg" value="Register">
     </form>
```

then i have my php code as:

```
if(isset($_POST["supreg"])){
//handles the $_POST from form 2

}

if(isset($_POST["cordreg"])){
//handles the $_POST from form 3
}
```

Comment: You tag `php` & `javascript`. Where is your code?

Comment: Yes, post your php and javascript code as well as tell us the condition for form-1 to send data to form-2 or form-3.

Comment: You could use javascript to show hide form 2 or form 3 when user select option. When user click submit button, in server you could check value of select option posted from browser and get value with each type.

Comment: please review the edited version

Comment: incidentally - in the above html your submit buttons have two value attributes! Should one of those be the name attribute??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps this might help a little? Forms named `supervisor` and `coordinator` represent your two hidden forms you mentioned - the event listener queries the DOM for those forms by their names and removes the `hidden` class from the selected form when the button is pressed. By changing the button in the first form to a simple button you don't submit the first form - otherwise you'd probably want to use GET as the method and do some other trickery

```
<?php
    if( $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST' && !empty( $_POST['register'] ) ){
        /* assign vars to filter user input */
        $args=array(
            'register'  =>  FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING,
            'username'  =>  FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING
        );

        /* reassign POST to the new filtered values & create variables */
        $_POST=filter_input_array( INPUT_POST, $args );
        extract( $_POST );

        /* process form submission */
        switch( $register ){
            case 'supreg':
                /* Supervisor registration form */
                $sql='insert into users (username) values (?)';
            break;
            case 'cordreg':
                /* Coordinator registration form */
            break;
        }


    }

?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang='en'>
    <head>
        <meta charset='utf-8' />
        <title>Select menu display</title>
        <style>
            .hidden{display:none}

            h1,
            [type='button']{text-transform:capitalize}

            [name='coordinator'],
            [name='supervisor']{padding:1rem;border:1px solid black;width:50%;}
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>

        <form action='#' name='choices' method='post'>
            <select name='load'>
                <option selected hidden disabled>Please Select
                <option value='supervisor'>Supervisor
                <option value='coordinator'>Coordinator
            </select>
            <input type='button' value='load registration form'>
        </form>

        <!-- hidden forms -->
        <form name='supervisor' class='hidden' method="post">
            <h1>supervisor</h1>
            <input type='text' name='username' value='Supervisor: Geronimo' />

            <input type='hidden' name='register' value='supreg' />
            <input type='submit' />
        </form>

        <form name='coordinator' class='hidden' method="post">
            <h1>coordinator</h1>
            <input type='text' name='username' value='Coordinator: Hiawatha' />

            <input type='hidden' name='register' value='cordreg' />
            <input type='submit' />
        </form>     




        <script>

            let form=document.forms.choices;
            let _class='hidden';



            /* ensure that the button is re-enabled */
            form.querySelector( 'select[name="load"]' ).addEventListener('change',function(e){
                form.querySelector( 'input[ type="button" ]' ).disabled=false
            });

            /* Process button click event */
            form.querySelector( 'input[ type="button" ]' ).addEventListener('click',function(e){

                /* ensure that all other forms are hidden initially */
                document.querySelectorAll('form').forEach( el=>{
                    if( el!=form && !el.classList.contains( _class ) ) el.classList.add( _class );
                });

                /* find the value the user has chosen from the select menu */
                let select=form.querySelector( 'select[ name="load" ]' );
                let choice=select.options[ select.options.selectedIndex ].value;

                /* Find the relevant form in the DOM and remove the class that hides it */
                document.querySelector( 'form[ name="'+choice+'" ]' ).classList.remove( _class );

                /* 
                    Disable the button that displays the form so it cannot be clicked 
                    again until new option is made from select menu
                */
                form.querySelector( 'input[ type="button" ]' ).disabled=true;
            });

        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: i was able to modify this code to fit my work... thanks alot

Answer (score 0):

You Want to submit ur form to an external PHP code right?
the way that comes my mind is when the PHP code executed you redirect to your index with a PHP link variable `p/ex:index.php?form=2`
then just create a function to see which is the value from `$_GET['form']` to display the form that correspond with that number
 well its not the best way to do that , you will fund challenges passing the variable to javascript but you can have an invisible input where u write on it by PHP and get the value on javascript

To do it in the right way I just can think in AJAX but I can't help you with that

Answer (score 0):

Well, You have not put up your PHP code or javascript so I am not getting into the hazard to use PHP right now.

you really don't need that submit button there,

it's simple as you know hide/show concepts.

first, create two div and put up both forms in separate divs and hide them.

then on change event of your dropbox show that div.

This is simple Javascript

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#purpose').on('change', function() {
      if ( this.value == 'supervisor')
      {
        $("#Coordinator").hide();
        $("#supervisor").show();
      }

      else if ( this.value == 'coordinator')
      {
        $("#supervisor").hide();
        $("#Coordinator").show();
      }
      else
      {
        $("#supervisor").hide();
        $("#Coordinator").hide();

      }
    });
});
```

Here is the fiddle for you. [jsfiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/8reLz9k4/)

Comment: Please add the relevant code and then the link to te jsfiddle

Comment: @Sfili_81 My code is relevant, thing is that Question was majorly updated i answered according to an old question, also it still fulfill all requirements if he just wants to show form on dropdown events